# drop-down menu JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a drop-down menu for my Website but I am not a boss in JavaScript so I take a ready-made drop-down menu in Internet and I improve that. But when I would it replace my

```
<a href="" title="Afficher le sous-menu">Voir Plus</a>
```

It work but when I click again on this links, the script no longer works.

The example here : http://jsfiddle.net/LZfY3/3/.
And the code:

CSS

```
#navigation {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    width: 630px;
    font: 1.2em "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    background: #ccc url(subMenu.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
}
#navigation h2 {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
#navigation h2 {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #000 url(menu-item.png) left bottom no-repeat;
}
#navigation .subMenuHidden, #navigation .toggleSubMenu{
    clear:both;
}
#navigation .subMenuHidden,  #navigation .subMenuVis {
    font-size: .8em;
    font-size: .9em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navigation div.subMenuHidden a {
    padding: 3px 20px;
    float:right;
}
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
li {
      height: 1px;
    }
```

JavaScript

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

$(document).ready( function () {
    // On cache les sous-menus
    // sauf celui qui porte la classe "open_at_load" :
    $("div.subMenu:not('.open_at_load')").hide();
    // On selectionne tous les items de liste portant la classe "toggleSubMenu"

    // et on remplace l'element span qu'ils contiennent par un lien :
    /*$("div.subMenuHidden span").each( function () {
        // On stocke le contenu du span :
        var TexteSpan = $(this).text();
        $(this).replaceWith('<a href="" title="Afficher le sous-menu">' + TexteSpan + '</a>') ;
    } ) ;*/

    // On modifie l'evenement "click" sur les liens dans les items de liste
    // qui portent la classe "toggleSubMenu" :
    $("div.subMenuHidden > a").click( function () {
        // Si le sous-menu etait deja ouvert, on le referme :
        if ($(this).prev("div.subMenu:visible").length != 0) {
            $(this).prev("div.subMenu").slideUp("normal", function () {$(this).next("a").replaceWith('<a href="" title="Afficher le sous-menu">voir plus/see more</a>') } );
        }
        // Si le sous-menu est cache, on ferme les autres et on l'affiche :
        else {
            $("div.subMenu").slideUp("normal", function () { $(this).next("a").replaceWith('<a href="" title="Afficher le sous-menu">voir plus/see more</a>') } );
            $(this).prev("div.subMenu").slideDown("normal", function () { $(this).next("a").replaceWith('<a href="" title="Afficher le sous-menu">voir moins/see less</a>') } );
        } 
        // On empêche le navigateur de suivre le lien :
        return false;
    });

} ) ;
```

HTML

```
<ul id="navigation">
        <li class="toggleSubMenu" style="position: static;"><h2 class="toggleSubMenuH2">Images / Photos</h2>
            <div class="subMenuVis">
                <div style="height: 100px; width: 178px; background-color: aqua; margin: 10; float: left;"></div>
                <div style="height: 100px; width: 178px; background-color: aqua; margin: 10; float: left;"></div>
                <div style="height: 100px; width: 178px; background-color: aqua; margin: 10; float: left;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="subMenuHidden"> 
                <div class="subMenu" style="display: none;">
                    <div style="height: 80px; width: 142px; background-color: aqua; margin: 0 0 10px 10px; float: left;"></div>
                    <div style="height: 80px; width: 142px; background-color: aqua; margin: 0 0 10px 10px; float: left;"></div>
                    <div style="height: 80px; width: 142px; background-color: aqua; margin: 0 0 10px 10px; float: left;"></div>
                    <div style="height: 80px; width: 142px; background-color: aqua; margin: 0 0 10px 10px; float: left;"></div>
                    <div style="height: 80px; width: 142px; background-color: aqua; margin: 0 0 10px 10px; float: left;"></div>
                    <div style="height: 80px; width: 142px; background-color: aqua; margin: 0 0 10px 10px; float: left;"></div>
                    <div style="height: 80px; width: 142px; background-color: aqua; margin: 0 0 10px 10px; float: left;"></div>
                    <div style="height: 80px; width: 142px; background-color: aqua; margin: 0 0 10px 10px; float: left;"></div>
                </div>
                <a href="" title="Afficher le sous-menu" id="caca">voir plus</a>  
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="toggleSubMenu" style="position: static;"><h2 class="toggleSubMenuH2">Vidéos</h2>
            <div class="subMenuVis">
                <div style="height: 100px; width: 178px; background-color: aqua; margin: 10; float: left;"></div>
                <div style="height: 100px; width: 178px; background-color: aqua; margin: 10; float: left;"></div>
                <div style="height: 100px; width: 178px; background-color: aqua; margin: 10; float: left;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="subMenuHidden"> 
                <div class="subMenu" style="display: none;">
                    <div style="height: 80px; width: 142px; background-color: aqua; margin: 0 0 10px 10px; float: left;"></div>
                    <div style="height: 80px; width: 142px; background-color: aqua; margin: 0 0 10px 10px; float: left;"></div>
                    <div style="height: 80px; width: 142px; background-color: aqua; margin: 0 0 10px 10px; float: left;"></div>
                    <div style="height: 80px; width: 142px; background-color: aqua; margin: 0 0 10px 10px; float: left;"></div>
                    <div style="height: 80px; width: 142px; background-color: aqua; margin: 0 0 10px 10px; float: left;"></div>
                    <div style="height: 80px; width: 142px; background-color: aqua; margin: 0 0 10px 10px; float: left;"></div>
                    <div style="height: 80px; width: 142px; background-color: aqua; margin: 0 0 10px 10px; float: left;"></div>
                    <div style="height: 80px; width: 142px; background-color: aqua; margin: 0 0 10px 10px; float: left;"></div>
                </div>
                <a href="" title="Afficher le sous-menu">voir plus</a> 
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Thanks.

Comment: @SquareCat suggested as an answer should be the one or if the script stops, it should be an error in javascript execution. Please let us know what the console says. right click->inspect element->console(tab). something in red! that starts usually with "Unexpected...". The comments seem to be in french which I hardly understand

Comment: The console say : event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery-1.10.2.js:5374

Comment: I would'nt recommend this, please try using an older version of jquery.. say 1.8 or 1.9 and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I change the version of jquery but it doesn't works maybe the script can't do action on the link which he created.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem seems to be the `a` variable, which is not defined (nor declared) in the given context:

```
$(a).replaceWith()
```

I think you wanted to use a selector instead?

```
$('a').replaceWith()
```

[See the updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/LZfY3/1/)

Comment: that Should be the one squarecat.. ;-)

Comment: Thanks but Excuse me because I have make a mistake when I copied out the script, the topic is update